# How to print element contents from ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

currently trying to print the details from an `ArrayList`.

The **ArrayList** below called **detailBook** is storing the details of another array, and so the `detailBook.get` method only returns the hash code. Any idea?

```
         String[] bookList = new String[100];
         String[]authorList = new String[100];
         ArrayList detailBook = new ArrayList();

        while(book.hasNextLine()){
            bookList[0] = book.nextLine();
            bookList[1] = book.nextLine();
            detailBook.add(bookList);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bookList));
            System.out.println(detailBook.get(0));
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the content of `detailBook`?

Comment: What does the `ArrayList` contain?

Comment: String[] bookList = new String[100];
       String[]authorList = new String[100];
       ArrayList detailBook = new ArrayList();
       
      while(book.hasNextLine()){
       bookList[0] = book.nextLine();
       bookList[1] = book.nextLine();
       detailBook.add(bookList);
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bookList));
       System.out.println(detailBook.get(0));

Comment: If `x` is an array, you should try `Arrays.toString(x)` to get a readable printout. It seems you are already using this to print `bookList`; just do the same for `detailBook.get(0)`.

Comment: Never, ever, use raw types! It's a `List<String[]>`, declare it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Since each object has `toString()` method, the default is displaying the class name representation, then adding `@` sign and then the hashcode. That's why you're getting the "weird" output.

According to your code in the comments (that you should put in your question), you have an `ArrayList` that contains s `String` array, `detailBook.get(0)` returns a `String[]`.

What you should do is:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(detailBook.get(0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
System.out.println(detailBook.get(0)[i]);
```

`i` would be the index for array.